# In Wordpress (Twentyfourteen, specifically) how can I have featured posts also shown in my post stream?

Tags: php, themes, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I've set up a wordpress using twentyfourteen. I've created a child theme and started tweaking my index page hoping to achieve this, but so far I haven't had any luck.

My end goal is this:

I would like featured posts to also show up on my homepage in the normal post stream (as if I didn't choose featured). Right now when i choose featured, it takes the post out of my stream of posts and sits it exclusively in my top featured section.

I looked into tweaking `twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts()` but I'm not really understanding why after it gets a featured post, it seems to flag it, or remove from the normal post flow.

Could someone put me on the right track to making this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the 2014 theme for WordPress is tricky. It has a method to filter out all the featured posts from the home page and it's hooked in.

The file that does this is in the **inc** folder in the twentyfourteen theme folder and is named *featured-content.php*

The function is `pre_get_posts`. What you might want to try is **commenting out** that block of code for that function and **commenting out** the below line in the same file:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array( __CLASS__, 'pre_get_posts' ) );
```

I'm not in the position to undo my custom modifications on my own WordPress site, but I at least confirmed through a test run that there were no other issues such as dependencies in other files on this function. Give it a try and let me know how it goes - if you find an issue that I may have overlooked, you can just undo the comments.

Comment: Hey there Thanks a lot for the reponse. The closest thing i could find in `featured-content.php` was this function: `do_action( 'twentyfourteen_featured_posts_before' );`. I tried swapping that with your code, but it seemed to break. Was this what you meant?

Comment: Ah, there's a file with the same name in the directory right under twentyfourteen. You went into that file, but the one you're looking for is under inc, so the path should be twentyfourteen/ **inc** /featured-content.php

I should have put the /inc/ in bold, as it doesn't stand out. My bad.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the follow up, that worked like a charm! Is there a way to overwrite the `Featured_Content::init()` function in my child theme? It's my understanding that an update to the theme will overwrite this change, right? Thanks again!

Comment: The function is hooked in, so you technically can work with remove_action and have it undo the line of code I posted. If you can remove the hook using your child theme, then the commenting out wouldn't be necessary. Check out this [**example**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action#Example) that talks about removing actions from classes. It seems relevant to what you'll need to do if you want to display featured posts in both the slider and home using your child theme rather than just commenting it out directly in the theme files.